# Rollup Font Awesome CSS?

Tags: font-awesome, rollup

I'm including [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) in a library project with:

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css';
```

When running locally, this works fine and I can use the Font Awesome classes to create icons.

But after I [`rollup`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) the project and include I get the error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css'

Other CSS files are being bundled into an output css file. Why not that one? Here's my `rollup.config.js`.

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs'
  },

  external: [
    'react',
    'react-dom',
    'lodash',
    'moment',
    'react-router-dom',
  ],

  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
      presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
    }),
    css({
      output: 'bundle.css'
    })
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is likely caused by Rollup not being able to resolve the bare module specifier (`'@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro...'` instead of `./path/to/@fortawesome...'`).

Try adding the [`@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/node-resolve) plugin:

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  //...
  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
      presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
    }),
    resolve(),
    css({
      output: 'bundle.css'
    })
  ],
};
``
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I was still getting errors around missing fonts. I didn't try to hard, though, as I just made fontawesome an optional peer dependency in the end.